# Updating value in nested page(not in widget tree) without refresh when I use provider pattern

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

I am making an app in the form of a news feed like facebook. I would like to make it user go through contenst in the feed and make them read more detail by clicking on the feed(`feedPage` to `postPage`).
I use Firestore as a backend and the provider pattern.

`feedPage` refers to StreamProvider and myUserData Provider(from main.dart)
Whenever the content is modified or changed or I clicked like, added a comment, it is updated immediately without the need to refresh.

```
// feed_page.dart

class FeedPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<List<Post>>.value(
      value: firestoreProvider.fetchAllPosts(),
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
        appBar: AppBar(
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          title: GestureDetector(
            child: Text('test'),

-----


  Container _postActions(
      BuildContext context, MyUserData myUserData, Post post) {
    return Container(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
            common_gap, common_gap, common_gap, common_gap),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                final route = MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => PostPage(myUserData.data, post));
                Navigator.of(context).push(route);
              },
```

the issue is in `post_page.dart`. When I access to postPage through **Navigator**, I could see all the details in the postPage. But when I modify something(such as clicking like/heart button, added a comment), I can't see any change in postPage.

```
// post_page.dart

class PostPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final User user;
  final Post post;

  const PostPage(this.user, this.post, {Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PostPageState createState() => _PostPageState();
}

class _PostPageState extends State<PostPage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: false,
        elevation: 0,
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.label_outline,
              color: Colors.grey[900],
              size: 30,
            ),
            onPressed: null,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Form(
        key: _formkey,
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: CustomScrollView(
                  slivers: <Widget>[
                    SliverToBoxAdapter(
                      child: _postItem(
                          context, widget.post.title, widget.post.content),
                    ),
                    SliverToBoxAdapter(
                      child: _postComments(),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              _commentField()
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Container _postActions(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
            common_gap, common_gap, common_gap, common_xl_gap),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: <Widget>[
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {},
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Image.asset('assets/comment.png',
                      width: 17, fit: BoxFit.cover),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: common_xxs_gap,
                  ),
                  Text("${widget.post.numOfComments}", // <-------------------------- my issue is here!
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13.0, color: Colors.black87))
                ],
              ),
            ),
)
    );
  }
```

For example, if I added a comment in this page, `widget.post.numOfComments in PostPage` should be updated immediately, but to get it updated I got to refresh it by going back to feedPage and return to postPage again.

I think it is because I do not set up provider or setState in postPage.
But I actually have no idea of how to use setState with FirebaseProvider.
And if possible, I want to use Provider either since it is nested in the feedPage(I know it is not in the widget tree of feedPage).

```
// firestore_provider.dart

class FirestoreProvider with Transformer {
  final Firestore _firestore = Firestore.instance;

  Future<void> attemptCreateUser({String userKey, String phone}) async {
    final DocumentReference userRef =
        _firestore.collection(COLLECTION_USERS).document(userKey);
    final DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await userRef.get();
    return _firestore.runTransaction((Transaction tx) async {
      if (!snapshot.exists) {
        await tx.set(userRef, User.getMapForCreateUser(userKey, phone));
      }
    });
  }

  Stream<User> connectMyUserData(String userKey) {
    return _firestore
        .collection(COLLECTION_USERS)
        .document(userKey)
        .snapshots()
        .transform(toUser);
  }

  Stream<List<User>> fetchAllUsers() {
    return _firestore
        .collection(COLLECTION_USERS)
        .snapshots()
        .transform(toUsers);
  }

  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> createNewPost(
      String postKey, Map<String, dynamic> postData) async {
    final DocumentReference postRef = _firestore
        .collection(COLLECTION_POSTS)
        .document(postKey); // 없으면 자동으로 Reference 생성됨.
    final DocumentSnapshot postSnapshot = await postRef.get();
    final DocumentReference userRef =
        _firestore.collection(COLLECTION_USERS).document(postData[KEY_USERKEY]);
    return _firestore.runTransaction((Transaction tx) async {
      if (!postSnapshot.exists) {
        await tx.update(userRef, {
          KEY_MYPOSTS: FieldValue.arrayUnion([postKey])
        });
        await tx.set(postRef, postData);
      }
    });
  }

  Stream<List<Post>> fetchAllPosts() {
    return _firestore
        .collection(COLLECTION_POSTS)
        .orderBy(KEY_POSTTIME, descending: true)
        .snapshots()
        .transform(toPosts);
  }

  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> createNewComments(
      String postKey, Map<String, dynamic> commentData) async {

    final DocumentReference postRef = _firestore
        .collection(COLLECTION_POSTS)
        .document(postKey); // 없으면 자동으로 Reference 생성됨.

    final DocumentSnapshot postSnapshot = await postRef.get();
    print(postSnapshot);
    final DocumentReference commentRef =
        postRef.collection(COLLECTION_COMMENTS).document();


    return _firestore.runTransaction((Transaction tx) async {
      if (postSnapshot.exists) {
        await tx.set(commentRef, commentData);
        int numOfComments = postSnapshot.data[KEY_NUMOFCOMMENTS];

        await tx.update(postRef, {KEY_NUMOFCOMMENTS: numOfComments + 1});
      }
    });
  }

  Stream<List<CommentModel>> fetchAllComments(String postKey) {
    return _firestore
        .collection(COLLECTION_POSTS)
        .document(postKey)
        .collection(COLLECTION_COMMENTS)
        .orderBy(KEY_COMMENTTIME)
        .snapshots()
        .transform(toComments);
  }
}

FirestoreProvider firestoreProvider = FirestoreProvider();
```

plz help.. thanks!

Comment: In this situation, I think you should be use streamBuilder to update value from Firebase

Comment: @darkness 

I am already using StreamProvider in feedPage...  the value 'post' I am passing to postPage is generated from Provider. 

I don't have any problem getting value from feedPage and using it in postPage. the issue is.. even though value is actually changed, it doesn't  show updated value(numOfComments) in postPage unless I refresh it.

Comment: You can try wrap the _postActions inside statefull or stateless

Comment: @darkness Thanks.... Do you mean I should wrap  '_postActions' in post_page.dart(the second code block) with streamBuilder?

Comment: Just write _postActions in another file with state full widget. Don't need wrap the  widget inside streamBuilder because you has use streambuilder above. Or you can wrap the _postActions inside Builder widget. May be something wrong with context.

Comment: Okay thanks. I will check this out!